# Problem with reading from StreamingAssets Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, file-io, windows-10

If the user installs the program to the **C:\Program Files (x86)** directory, then when reading from StreamingAssets, an exception appears `UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "C:\Program Files (x86) ... is denied"`
The user does not have administrator rights. Running as administrator doesn't help. I have no control over where the user installs the program. This is how I read the file

```
string pathToDefaultScene = $"{Application.streamingAssetsPath}/DefaultScene.crscene";
using (var stream = new FileStream(pathToDefaultScene , FileMode.Open))
{
    stream.Read(sceneLengthBytes, 0, sizeof(int));
    stream.Read(imageLengthBytes, 0, sizeof(int));
    stream.Read(metadataLengthBytes, 0, sizeof(int));
    var sceneLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(sceneLengthBytes, 0);
    imageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(imageLengthBytes, 0);
    var metadataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(metadataLengthBytes, 0);
    sceneBytes = new byte[sceneLength];
    imageBytes = new byte[imageLength];
    metadataBytes = new byte[metadataLength];
    stream.Read(sceneBytes, 0, sceneLength);
    stream.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageLength);
    stream.Read(metadataBytes, 0, metadataLength);
}
```

Comment: You might want to use Path.Combine() instead of a hard coded '/' as seperator character in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to change the install directory. The best solution will be to create an installer of your build using tools like Inno Setup. if you can create a new build.

You can read the following for more details.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/901085/write-access.html

Comment: The link you're referring to is about write access, but the question is about READ access?